# Applying a sort order to existing data using SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some existing data that I need to apply a "SortOrder" to based upon a few factors:

1. The ordering starts at "1" for any given Owner
2. The ordering is applied alphabetically (basically following an `ORDER BY Name`) to increase the sort order.
3. Should two items have the same name (as I've illustrated in my data set), we can apply the lower sort order value to the item with the lower id.

Here is some sample data to help illustrate what I'm talking about:

What I have:

```
Id      OwnerId   Name                     SortOrder  
------  -------   ----------------------   ---------  
1        1         A Name                   NULL                        
2        1         C Name                   NULL  
3        1         B Name                   NULL  
4        2         Z Name                   NULL  
5        2         Z Name                   NULL  
6        2         A Name                   NULL
```

What I need:

```
Id      OwnerId   Name                     SortOrder  
------  -------   ----------------------   ---------  
1        1         A Name                   1                        
3        1         B Name                   2  
2        1         C Name                   3  
6        2         A Name                   1  
4        2         Z Name                   2   
5        2         Z Name                   3
```

This could either be done in the form of an `UPDATE` statement or doing an `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT FROM (...)` if it's easier to move the data from one table to the next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy - use a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function:

```
;WITH OrderedData AS
(
   SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerId ORDER BY Name, Id) AS 'SortOrder'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM OrderedData
ORDER BY OwnerId, SortOrder
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause groups your data into group for each value of `OwnerId` and the `ROW_NUMBER()` then starts counting at 1 for each new group of data.

**Update:** If you want to update your table to set the `SortOrder` column - try this:

```
;WITH OrderedData AS
(
   SELECT 
      Id, OwnerId, Name, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerId ORDER BY Name, Id) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE OrderedData
SET SortOrder = RowNum
```

That should set the `SortOrder` column to the values that the `ROW_NUMBER()` function returns

Comment: This works great in the select - insert into case, would you be willing to post a variant of this solution that works for update as well?

Comment: @DanP: added an update to my answer - is that what you're looking for??